# Why we need to use Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Sorry for this question, but I really don't understand why I have to use `redux` for `react` if I can make the same with core `react` features. I can make `this.setState({})` and pass this state value between components, and the application will be working in the same way. What is the advantage of `redux`?

Answer (score 1):

Redux is the most used state management for many React applications for many reasons:

- Reduce and manage complexity when the app is scaling.
- Ensure same state to be shared among multiples React components.
- Reduce the number of props being passed throughout the multiple
  levels of components.
- Prevent using setState a lot, which can damage your component
  performance.
- Redux asserts with its one global object to always have one single
  source of truth.